# Can a likelihood function be integrated to find the CDF and probabilities?

Tags: bayesian, likelihood

Likelihood analysis uses the likelihood function:

$L(\Theta | data) = P(data | \Theta)$

to determine how *likely* it is that some value is the true population parameter ($\Theta$) compared to some other value. With likelihood analysis, we can't determine the *probability* of a value being $\Theta$, only it's relative *likelihood* compared to other possible values of $\Theta$.

If we want to look at the actual *probabilities* of possible values of $\Theta$, we need to use Bayesian analysis:

$P(\Theta | data) = \frac{P(data | \Theta)P(\Theta)}{P(data)} = C*L(\Theta | data)$

To do this we need to determine the proper prior to use, which can be a touchy subject in statistics.

**My question is**: If I want to find the *probabilities* of possible values of $\Theta$ **without dealing with a prior**, could I simply normalize the function $C*L(\Theta | data)$ and integrate it (or use MCMC accomplish the same thing)?

Wouldn't this method give me a CDF of $P(\Theta | data)$ without using a prior at all?

Comment: What measure are you integrating the likelihood against?  (Whatever your answer to that might be will be tantamount to explaining what prior distribution you are using.)

Comment: @whuber I would be integrating to find cumulative probabilities of the tails; to find a credibility interval around a value of $\theta$, for instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assume $P(\theta) \propto C$, but then you are using a uniform prior over the domain for $\theta$. So, although your goal was to avoid dealing with a prior, you have actually used a uniform prior.

Here are some issues with this approach:

- It is not invariant to the parameterization you chose for the model. Thus the development of the Jeffreys prior.
- The normalizing integral, $\int C * L(\theta|data) d\theta$, might not be finite. If using MCMC, this could be worse because it might not be obvious.
- Uniform priors are often extremely unrealistic and extremely informative. Thus, you went from an idea of avoiding the prior to using a prior that is extremely informative toward implausible values.